# Is there a version of ELMAH for .NET 4?

Tags: .net-4.0, elmah

I'd like to use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) in an ASP.NET MVC 2 application running on .NET 4, but according to the project hosting site on Google code, it only supports .NET 1.1 and 2.0.

Is there a .NET 4 version of ELMAH already, or do I have to download the source and update whatever breaks myself?

Answer (score 3):

Elmah works perfectly fine for ASP.NET 4.0.

However, there are a few tricks in getting it setup to work perfectly on an MVC website.

I have recently starting blogging about this topic so be sure to check out my blog series on logging in MVC. The first article covers getting Elmah set up and running for MVC using all the tricks that you can find about it on StackOverflow.

There is a link to downloadable code at the end of the article. Hope that helps.

http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am using .NET 4.0 and I dont about a new version.... but I am using the elmah 1.1 and it works....:)..You may have to change source though to add custom fields or log additional values..which is bit of a pain...but get started [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well it's open source nothing should prevent you from recompiling it using the .NET 4.0 framework.

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/a99txfy5%28v=vs.140%29) has some information about running pre .NET4 web apps and .NET4 web apps in a server.

**EDIT:**

Actually you won't need to recompile ELMAH. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/in-process-side-by-side-execution)  and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110817012705/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/clrteam/archive/2009/06/03/in-process-side-by-side-part1.aspx) article the In-Process side by side execution should do the trick.

Comment: I know it's open source, and I was just about to download it when I realized that I don't want to reinvent the wheel. If there already is a .NET 4 port, the SO community would know :P

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question so I downloaded the [1.1 src](https://web.archive.org/web/20160102070051/http://code.google.com/p/elmah/downloads/detail?name=ELMAH-1.1-src.zip), opened it up in visual studio 2010, changed the project to target 4.0 and rebuilt it. I then dropped the dll in my ASP.NET MVC 2.0 app and it has worked fine.